# Android: menu displaying at screen bottom

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I was trying to create a menu, and add some actions "ifRoom" using code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/search_description" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
        android:title="@string/menu_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_preference"
        android:title="@string/menu_preferences"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        />
</menu>
```

But what i got is the menu is displaying at the bottom... 
I want it to be at top of the screen...

Any idea what happened here?  Thanks!

Screenshot link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/knECg.png

Below is the MainActivity.java   onCreateOptionaMenu method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        // Moved from onCreate -- Retrieve the Search View and configure/enable it
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())    );

        return true;
    }
```